# cbind equivalent of rbindlist in data.table?

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I have a list containing 12 dataframes of equal lengths (about 40 million rows each). The dataframes have four variables each and three of the variables (Lat, Lon & time) are common to all. I'm running into problems merging the list into a single dataframe due to memory limitations, although I was successful using `data.table`. But the times when the merging was successful, the length of the resultant dataframe was unreasonably longer than expected (about 147 million as opposed to 40 million).

I have tried different approaches but only `rbindlist` from `data.table` did not hit the memory limit but produced the unexpected result described above.

Based on @Roland's comment, I guess my question is whether there is `cbind` equivalent of the function `rbindlist` in `data.table`.

Here's my code

```
weather_list = list(bui, dc, dmc, dsr, ffmc, 
                    fwi, isi, prec, rh, temp, 
                    uwind, vwind)

weather_data = rbindlist(weather_list, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

Expected results: 15 columns and 40 million rows

```
# Temp   Prec  RH   ...    Lon  Lat  Time 
#  13    120  70   ...    -138  60    1
#  25    37   25   ...    -140  69.5  1
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what this function does. It doesnot merge/join by "common variables". It literally just row-binds.

Comment: Can you post a smaller reproducible example?

Comment: I have modified my question based on @Roland's comment. I think it's a matter of finding the right function /memory management as opposed to being a data issue

Comment: I think you might be looking for merge possibly in conjunction with Reduce.

Comment: I already tried that but couldn't overcome the memory problem

Comment: As @Roland pointed, `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by), df)` is the R {base} way to go. If you're unable due to memory limitation, you've got to work in disk instead. There's lightweight alternatives, such as {sqlite} and {duckdb}. Even if some package can work that load, tomorrow your data may get bigger and bigger. Once in big data realm, it is useful to learn alternatives.

Comment: Yes, that was what I tried and didn't work due to memory limitation. I haven't thought about working from a disk. I will look into ```SQLite```. Thanks.

Comment: Both cbindlist and mergelist are new functions waiting in data.table PR branches